# CSS image Size?

Tags: css, image

There...

```
#logoWrapper{
  background-image: url(../image/bg_img.jpg);
  height:86px;
  width:100%;
  }
```

Q>  How to fix the size of the image get into #logoWapper same with its Wapper automatically?

```
#logoWrapper img{       // not work
  height:86px;
  width:100%;
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the complete class css

Comment: I would like to add that #logoWrapper img affects all <img> tags inside #logoWrapper ..therefore no css background images will be affected. In these cases using img tags would mostlikely be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

For a background image in CSS3 if you want to stretch not repeat you can use `background-size: 100%;`

Documented here http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspbgsize.htm

Alternatively you can layer a absolute positioned image inside a relative positioned div and add an additional wrapper.

```
<style>
#wrapper {
position:relative;
...
}
#wrapper div, #wrapper img {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
...
}
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
<img ... >
<div> this goes on top of image</div>
</div>
```

Comment: #logoWrapper{
  background-image: url(../image/bg_img.jpg);
  height:86px;
  width:100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
  thank you! you mean like this? but not work....

Comment: That would be the coding for modern browsers ... the alternative is for the last decade browser (not to name names).

Comment: @SoonYeoung: According to w3schools: "The background-size property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 5+." If you want this to work in all browsers, you should use an img inside a div instead, like Wayne suggests.

Comment: Any other way? without <img> tag!!

Comment: Hummmm! you mean, no way but background-repeat : repeat-x;

Comment: Why is it necessary not to use img tag?

Comment: Lollero if may be necessary if using a CMS system that only gives you access to css and not the html. Unfortunately earlier versions of CSS do not allow sizing of background images ... you can background-position them to center and allow more or less material to be cropped off on the left and right sides.

Comment: @Wayne Very true, though i believe most / a lot of them  allow inserting images at least in the logo area. Second thing im curious about is why does the size need to be defined by the outer element.. I can imagine situation but then again I dont quite know why there would even be such situation.

Comment: @Lollero I am making an assumption from the question that text or some material needs to be place on a img which is why the image needs to be a background. ... I've ran into the need to do this myself many times ... Hence the wrapper is being used to layer the img as a background with div being placed on top ... the wrapper positioned relative becomes the top left of any absolute positioned content. Whatever is coded in the html first becomes the background with additional elements working their way to the finial one on top.